# Listed Frequency of Different Strings in a Particular Column

Tags: shell, command-line, text-processing, uniq

I need to figure it out how many times a particular string shows up in column 4.

This is my data:

```
25 48656721 48656734 FAM132B ENSCAFT00000019683 4 0.51 
X 53969937 53969950 FAM155B ENSCAFT00000026508 5 0.57 
3 42203721 42203906 FAM169B ENSCAFT00000017307 5 0.54 
36 28947780 28947831 FAM171B ENSCAFT00000046981 5 0.51 
10 45080519 45080773 FAM171B ENSCAFT00000003744 9 -0.53 
3 61627122 61627446 FAM193A ENSCAFT00000023571 13 0.64 
3 61626373 61626466 FAM193A ENSCAFT00000023571 6 0.51 
15 55348822 55349196 FAM193A ENSCAFT00000045012 5 0.52
```

This is a portion of my data. So, I'd want the output to be:

```
1 FAM132B
1 FAM155B
1 FAM169B
2 FAM171B
3 FAM193A
```

And so on - for the rest of my data. What's a command that would work?

Comment: Are you looking for a dynamic count on all data? IE You need to know how many times each occurance of an entry appears, you don't know how many different types of entries there may be, or what t hose entries may be? Or do you have a set number of potential entries that you are aware of, and want a count of those known entries?

Comment: I only see two "FAM193A" in your sample data? And, do you care if the output is sorted by column 4?

Comment: @Gravy My data consists of 2066 lines. Above I just have 8 sample lines.

Comment: @JeffSchaller You're absolutely right! That was a mistake on my part. I've edited it now. Thanks! And yes I would like it sorted by column 4

Comment: @Justin use sort -k
  -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
              start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line).  See POS  syn‐
              tax below

Comment: Justin, if one of the solutions worked for you, please mark it as accepted; thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simplistic solution would be to use `awk` to pull column 4; `uniq -c` to count them; and another `sort` to put them in order by the second column (the old column 4 data):

```
awk '{print $4}' < data | uniq -c | sort -k2
```

On your (updated) sample input, this gives:

```
  1 FAM132B
  1 FAM155B
  1 FAM169B
  2 FAM171B
  3 FAM193A
```

Comment: Ooo, this one works great as well! Thank you for that and your explanation!

Comment: @Jeff Schaller I messed up here can you give me a hand? I was with:
sort -k4 | awk '{print  $4, $3,$2,$1}' | uniq -c
     
How did you get the first field as a counter?

Comment: @vfbsilva you are including columns 3, 2, and 1 in your awk output when you should not; doing so changes uniq's input (and thus output)

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`:

```
awk '{a[$4]++} END{for(s in a){print a[s]" "s}}' file
```

- `a[$4]++` increments the array element whose index has the name of the 4th column. When finishing trough the file, that array contains counters of all occurences of the 4th column.
- `END{}`: indicates a block of code that runs when awk is trough the file.

  - `for(s in a)` run trough the array...
  - `print a[s]" "s}` ... and print its values and indexes.

---

The output:

```
1 FAM169B
3 FAM193A
1 FAM132B
1 FAM155B
2 FAM171B
```

Comment: `print a[s], s` seen better

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the delimiter is a single space:

```
cut -d' ' -f4 infile | sort | uniq -c
```

---

Note that `uniq` filters *adjacent* matching lines so you need to `sort` first e.g. with this input:

```
FAM193A
FAM155B
FAM169B
FAM171B
FAM132B
FAM193A
FAM132A
FAM132B
FAM155B
FAM169B
FAM171B
FAM171A
FAM193A
FAM132A
```

using `sort | uniq -c` produces:

```
  2 FAM132A
  2 FAM132B
  2 FAM155B
  2 FAM169B
  1 FAM171A
  2 FAM171B
  3 FAM193A
```

while `uniq -c | sort -k2` produces:

```
  1 FAM132A
  1 FAM132A
  1 FAM132B
  1 FAM132B
  1 FAM155B
  1 FAM155B
  1 FAM169B
  1 FAM169B
  1 FAM171A
  1 FAM171B
  1 FAM171B
  1 FAM193A
  1 FAM193A
  1 FAM193A
```